# Way arround for returning multiple lists in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a method which returns list in JSON format using hibernate and Spring MVC as Rest.

```
@RequestMapping(value="{userid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<IterationInfo> getIterationInfoInJSON(@PathVariable int userid) 
{
Configuration con = new Configuration();
con.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory SF = con.buildSessionFactory();
Session session= SF.openSession();
Transaction TR = session.beginTransaction();
Query query=session.createQuery("from IterationInfo");
List<IterationInfo> listiterationinfo=query.list();
session.close();
SF.close();
return listiterationinfo;
}
```

IterationInfo is the POJO class with getter/setters.But I have multiple POJO classes and using Hibernate Queries I want to return multiple lists.Is there a way arround to return multiple lists??

Comment: Most simplistically, you could call these methods sequentially- is there some reason you don't want to do this?

Comment: Have you tried a List of Lists?

Comment: @GlenPierce no havent tried it.I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @ScaryWombat how to do it sequentially??I have a URI mapped with userid.If I write multiple methods it throws an error saying duplicate REQUEST MAPPING

Comment: You could use Ajax

Comment: OK.Any reference where to read or any links will be helpful as I havent tried Ajax

Comment: The question is not clear can you provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

**Return** can return only one meaning, as I know. But you can wrap your list in other list, for example.